# GetVolumeInformationA returns no value for local disk

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, disk

I have following function which can be used to retrieve disk label by disk letter

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void GetVolumeLabel(char volume)
{
    char drive[4] = { ' ',':','\\'};
    drive[0] = volume;
    char VolumeName[MAX_PATH];
    if (!GetVolumeInformationA(
            (LPCSTR)drive,
            (LPSTR)VolumeName,
            sizeof(VolumeName),
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            0)
        )
    {
        cout << "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << VolumeName;
    }
}
int main()
{
    GetVolumeLabel('C');
    return 0;
}
```

But when i try to get label for disk "C", i get empty string and don`t udnerstand why. But, if for example, i use "D" (which is letter of inserted USB) instead of "C", this function successfully prints correct name. So, how i can get label for "C" or at least, how can i determine that the disk is local?

Comment: Check Windows Disk Management utility. The main system C disk typically has an empty volume name.

Comment: thank you, you are right... disk C has an empty volume name

Comment: Site usage note: have a good reason when using the C language tag with code that's obviously C++. Because the question is about the C Drive is not good enough.

Comment: @user4581301 Here the only reason to restrict the tag to `c++` (vs. `c`) is the use of streams, which is largely cosmetic here. Otherwise, the bulk/thrust of the question is largely language agnostic.

Comment: ***disk C has an empty volume name***  So the result is correct and the program works correctly and this is just a case of user error because the drive has an empty volume name?

Comment: @drescherjm I believe there are 2: EFI/ESP (for UEFI) + recovery. The first volume is not C anymore. It's not user error or bad configuration.

Comment: I just tested and the code worked for me and returned the correct volume name for c:\ on windows11. And C:\ is the 2nd partition on my SSD, the first is EFI and the 3rd is Recovery. In my Case I named my OS partition `Windows`

Comment: Close voters: where is the typo?

Comment: I thought the OP admitted in the 2nd comment that their `C:` has no volume name. As a result returning nothing is the correct result.